# Blender Nested UI Lists

Tags: python, interface

Please, I would to know if anyone have an idea about How to make a nested lists in blender UI?. "Nested Lists" means I can add children to each list element. The same behavior can be found in the Outliner when an object has children. I've used bpy.types.UIList it's works fine but no support for children for the list element.

Thanks,
Mostafa

Comment: Its not possible